# Start to play a video tag with jquery.play()

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I want the video start to play as soon as the absolute div over it is faded out but nothing works even with javascript or autoplay, without controls enabled it does not want to play. Any idea?

Here is the HTML

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" style="position:relative;background-color:#2d2d2d;display:block;">
```

Here is the script:

```
$('#post1403171021 #playArrowAnimation, #post1403171021 #cap').fadeOut(0, function(){ $("#post1403171021 #video").play(); this.animation = 1; }) });
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$("#post1403171021 #video")[0].play();`

Comment: I tried it now and nothing it wont work

Comment: desktop or mobile?

Comment: Mobile cause im traveling and have nothing else at the moment but it should work then with the controls it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the console: `$(#video")[0].play();`

It works in this example below, so you're either using the worng ID for the post or video is not yet loaded at the time you call the `play`.

Good luck!

```js
$('#loading').fadeOut(2000,function(){
  $('#video')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Hiding HTML5 Video Controls using CSS Pseudo selectors -->
<div id="loading" >loading</div>
<video width="300" id="video">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```